# SQL Server "The conversion of the varchar value '99101500728' overflowed an int column."

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This is my issue: when I run this query, there is no problem and returns the results as expected

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.OpId = b.OpId
INNER JOIN c ON b.AdId = c.AdId
INNER JOIN d ON c.AdId = d.AdId
INNER JOIN e ON a.CId = e.CId
INNER JOIN f ON b.OpId = f.OpId
INNER JOIN g ON a.AdRId = g.AdRId
INNER JOIN s ON c.AdSId = s.AdSId 
WHERE f.document = '52147896'
```

However, when I try to execute it using the EXEC command, it does not work!!

Here is the problematic code

```
declare @document varchar(20) = '52147896' --This is the correct type for this attribute since I took it directly from the table type
DECLARE @SELECT2 nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM a inner join  b ON 
a.OpId = b.OpId
INNER JOIN c ON b.AdId = c.AdId
INNER JOIN d ON c.AdId = d.AdId
INNER JOIN e ON a.CId = e.CId
INNER JOIN f ON b.OpId = f.OpId
INNER JOIN g ON a.AdRId = g.AdRId
INNER JOIN s ON c.AdSId = s.AdSId WHERE 
f.document = '+@document
```

And this is the error I get:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The conversion of the varchar value '99101500728' overflowed an int column.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're ever having trouble constructing a dynamic query, then instead of running `EXEC ... @SELECT2`, try doing a `SELECT @SELECT2` and then copying the result directly into a new query window. In this case, doing so would have shown you the difference between your dynamically constructed query and your original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the type is a string, then inclose the value in single quotes:

```
. . . 
f.document = '''+ @document + ''''
```

Better yet, use parameters and pass the value in using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: +1, but I think it's worth explaining why parameterization should really be the preferred approach here, or perhaps including a link like https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: Thank you! that was it! I did not realized that the 3-quote was the way to do it!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The difference that's causing the error lies on this line:

```
f.document = '52147896' -- Expression without EXEC
```

versus

```
f.document = 52147896 -- Expression with EXEC
```

On the second case, since you are comparing against an integer value, the SQL enging will convert the column `f.document` to integer to do the comparison, as stated by the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/eu-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). When it tries to convert, the varchar value `'99101500728'` is too big for an int a fails.

To solve it, write your value as string literal by adding single quotes before and after:

```
declare @document varchar(20) = '52147896' --This is the correct type for this attribute since I took it directly from the table type
DECLARE @SELECT2 nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM a inner join  b ON 
a.OpId = b.OpId
INNER JOIN c ON b.AdId = c.AdId
INNER JOIN d ON c.AdId = d.AdId
INNER JOIN e ON a.CId = e.CId
INNER JOIN f ON b.OpId = f.OpId
INNER JOIN g ON a.AdRId = g.AdRId
INNER JOIN s ON c.AdSId = s.AdSId WHERE 
f.document = '''+@document + ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause is passing an integer value.

```
WHERE f.document = 52147896
```

This is causing an implicit conversion of f.document to an INT data type.  One of your ID values has a character string of 99101500728, but this will not convert to an INT data type.

You can fix your dynamic SQL by escaping the single quotes so that your WHERE clause passes the value as a string

```
'WHERE f.document = ''' + @document + ''''
```

which will generate

```
WHERE f.document = '52147896'
```